# Why django-star-ratings not displaying the stars while template loads?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have added django-star-rating to my app but the template does not display the stars.I have added a rating field in AlbumImage class in models.py, and tried to iterated though a list of images(photos) but the star rating does not appear. I didn't edit the views.py.

models.py:

```
class AlbumImage(models.Model):
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='albums', processors=[ResizeToFit(1280)], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 70})
    thumb = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='albums', processors=[ResizeToFit(300)], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 80})
    album = models.ForeignKey('album', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=uuid.uuid4)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=70, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ratings = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='object_list')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ratings
```

views.py:

```
class AlbumDetail(DetailView):
    model = Album

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(AlbumDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the images
        context['images'] = AlbumImage.objects.filter(album=self.object.id)

        return context
```

template:

```
{% load ratings %}
    {% for item in object_list %}
       {{item.image}} and {{item.ratings}}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: None of this worked, good luck to another answerer!**

---

Based off of the [usage](https://github.com/wildfish/django-star-ratings#usage) on the readme, I think you're meant to have you're meant to use their custom tag `{% ratings <object> %}`, and you need to ensure that you have in your base or current template the CSS and JS scripts, like so:

Also you need to iterate through the 'images' variable:

#### templates

base html:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
...
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'star-ratings/css/star-ratings.css' %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'star-ratings/js/dist/star-ratings.min.js' %}"></script>
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

current html:

```
{% load ratings %}

{% for image in images %}
    {% ratings image %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, I have included those css and javascript, but it does not display the star ratings.

Comment: What do you see when doing the {% rating item %}

Comment: It didn't resolve. Where could i find the reference to queryset `object_list`?

Comment: Wait a minute! You're right, let me update my answer (need the formatting)

Comment: Sorry, It didn't. I thought {{ item.ratings}} or similar syntax is needed in template, but can't be sure since this didn't work too.I don't see how the django-star-ratings is related to the field ratings in AlbumImage in models.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180002/discussion-between-stefanjcollier-and-kaleab).